# How can I call a method for a <button> where I build the html up as a string?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is for a Blazor InteractiveServer app. I am creating the html for an Azure Maps popup. I create the html as follows:

```
var html = new StringBuilder("<div style=\"padding:10px;color:black\"><p>Click to go to the specific profile</p><ul>");
foreach (var pin in clusters)
{
    var name = ConvertToString(pin.Properties["Name"]);
    var url = ConvertToString(pin.Properties["ProfileUrl"]);
    var id = ConvertToInt(pin.Properties["Id"]);
    html.Append($"<li><button @onclick=\"OnSelectPin(id)\">{name}</button></li>");
}
html.Append("</ul></div>");
```

When the user clicks - it does not call the `OnSelectPin()` method.

```
private void OnSelectPin(int id)
{
    // do something
}
```

How can I get the html I pop up to call OnSelectPin()?

Comment: You could make a `href=` work but not an `@onclick`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yeah, I've got href working fine. The thing is, I'd rather make a popup on the existing page visible instead of going to another page, or even this same page with a url that has all the parameters for the popup. But I was afraid that I would get your answer - can't do it. Oh well :( as always, thank you.

Comment: Can't you trigger the popup from OnParametersSet ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman How can I set a parameter from the href=? My use case is I have an Azure Map up. On it I have an Azure Map SDK popup up with links. For the case of multiple entities at the same location on a clustered pin. I have a hidden DxPopup component that I want to populate and then show when they click the link for the selected entity. How can I do that? TIA

Comment: I think you'll need to use the native JS event, that raises an event through JSInterop.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you. I'll ask how badly they want this before I dive into doing this.